# SelectList always null on POST causes Model State to be Invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I understand that the SelectListItems are meant to not return back the items on post and perhaps be null, but because of this my ModelState.IsValid condition is always false and the Studies field which contains the list is the one with the invalid attribute. I tried different methods and am stuck on resolving this

**View**

```
 <label asp-for="Studies" class="form-label"></label>
 <select asp-for="SelectedStudyGuid" asp-items="@Model.Studies" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
   <option value="">Select Study</option>
 </select>
 <span asp-validation-for="SelectedStudyGuid" class="text-danger"></span>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class AddStudyViewModel
{
    public string ParticipantGuid { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Studies { get; set; }
    public string SelectedStudyGuid { get; set; }
    
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
  private List<SelectListItem> GetStudyCatalog()
    {
        return _repo.GetStudyCatalog().Select(s => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = s.Name,
            Value = s.Guid
        }).ToList();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult AddStudy(string participantGuid)
    {
        var model = new AddStudyViewModel
        {
            Studies = GetStudyCatalog(),
            ParticipantGuid = participantGuid
        };
        
        return PartialView("_AddStudyModal", model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddStudy(AddStudyViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           var response= _repo.AddStudy(model.SelectedStudyGuid, model.ParticipantGuid, model.StartDate, model.EndDate);
           
            if (response.Success)
            {
                TempData["Message"] = response.Message;
                return RedirectToAction("EditParticipant", new {id = response.NewGuid});
            }
        }

        model.Studies = GetStudyCatalog();
        return PartialView("_AddStudyModal", model);
    }
```

Comment: You can be failing for a number of reasons 1) Connection never completes so you do not get a response 2) Processing in server fails and server never sends back a response4 3) Server sends back a response with a status that doesn't equal 200 OK 4) Server sends back a response with a status of 200 OK but IActionResult doesn't match the model.  Which type failure are you getting?

Comment: Probably it doesn't return the SelectListItem in the model because you don't have any input field for the list. So when the form post back to the controller it doesn't build your model with the SelectListItem. But why post back the SelectListItem? Remove it from the ViewModel and pass it to the View through TempData, or ViewBag or other temporary storage

Comment: @jdweng A response is coming back but the Studies is what is invalid due to it being null

Comment: The real issue is you are sending a bad request that is getting back null data and need to fix the request (or the server has a bug).  But you still need to be able to handle exception at the client.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling?force_isolation=true

Comment: @Steve the Viewbag solved this thank you! I was using a model to bind because I thought it was better practice than Viewbag's. If you post an answer I can mark it as solved

Comment: Can you show your GetStudyCatalog method and StudyCatalog class pls?

Comment: StudyCatalog Class:

public partial class StudyCatalogItem
    {
        public StudyCatalogItem()
        {
            Studies = new HashSet<Study>();
        }

        public string Guid { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Study> Studies { get; set; }
    }

GetStudyCatalog: 
    public IEnumerable<StudyCatalogItem> GetStudyCatalog()
    {
        return _context.Studycatalogitems.ToList();
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen only if you use net 6. To fix it simply make Studies nullable

```
public List<SelectListItem>? Studies { get; set; }
```

or what is the smart developers do , they just remove nullables from the projests

```
 <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <!--<Nullable>enable</Nullable>-->
```

to use a ViewBag instead of a ViewModel is very unprofessional

Comment: I am using .Net 6. I was thinking to make it nullable but all the example I saw did not do this.

Comment: @EitanK I hate the new net 6 feature, and the worst that they made it default in  net6 projects. A lot of people dont realize it  and waste a lot of time trying to find the bag. But IMHO make nullable is much better then using ViewBag. ViewBag is the last choise.  Dont use ViewBag if  you still have any another choise.

Comment: @Sarge just tried it and it works nicely, thank you!

Comment: @Serge what's the problem with a ViewBag? Why is it best to post back that info into the ViewModel when you can rebuild on the server side or even extract from a cache? Passing this info in the ViewBag makes it clear that you don't have any plan to use that in the server side. Of course this is my opinion but I am curious to know why you prefer the ViewModel approach

Answer (score 1):

The problem is originated when you click your button to submit the form data back to the controller.

At this point the client side code sends the input fields present on the form and you don't have an input field that contains the SelectListItem. The *SelectedStudyGuid* select list is for that field, not for the whole Studies.

The AddStudyViewModel instance received in the post action is rebuilt on the server side using the data sent by the client side and thus you have a null for the Studies property.

Usually the SelectListItem data is not needed on the post action but only in the get action and you can simply pass it using some temporary storage like the ViewBag

So you can fix with

**MODEL**

```
public class AddStudyViewModel
{
    public string ParticipantGuid { get; set; }

    public string SelectedStudyGuid { get; set; }
    
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult AddStudy(string participantGuid)
{
    var model = new AddStudyViewModel
    {
        ParticipantGuid = participantGuid
    };
    ViewBag.Studies = GetStudyCatalog(),
    return PartialView("_AddStudyModal", model);
}
```

**VIEW**

```
 <label asp-for="Studies" class="form-label"></label>
 <select asp-for="SelectedStudyGuid" asp-items="@ViewBag.Studies" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
   <option value="">Select Study</option>
 </select>
 <span asp-validation-for="SelectedStudyGuid" class="text-danger"></span>
```